# Amarok and MusicBrainz Audio Fingerprinting

Tags: amarok, musicbrainz

Amarok 2.8 supports searching MusicBrainz by an audio-fingerprint. However this feature doesn't seem to work for me -- for example if I remove the ID3 tags from a known song and click on "Get Tags from MusicBrainz" I get no results.

From the Amarok manual:

> Amarok 2.8 has the ability to guess tags from the MusicBrainz
>   database. Click the Get Tags from MusicBrainz, wait a moment for the
>   database to be searched for matches, and then Update Tags, or Cancel.
>
> If you have the packages libofa and ffmpeg installed, and Amarok is
>   compiled with them, Musicbrainz will be able to use "fingerprinting"
>   (the MusicDNS service) to search for albums and tracks without good
>   filenames or existing tags.

I have both `libofa0` and `ffmpeg` installed, but this feature isn't working. By looking at the output of `ldd amarok` it doesn't seem that Amarok is even trying to load `libofa`. Is there something I'm missing, or do I need to compile Amarok manually with `libofa` in order to get it work?

Comment: Just tested this, and it's not working for me either (out of the box) ... Maybe you really have to do something manually